# Ubuntu 18.04 screen on right side is going out of display

Tags: monitor

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my dell i5 4th gen PC. I use Panasonic 55cm (22 inch) Full HD LED TV/Monitor. The right side of the display is out of screen, scroll bar is not visible and close window is not fully visible.

Comment: Check TV settings if it's using Scaling, 16:9, 4:3, etc.

Comment: yeah. i checked with TV settings. needed some settings in the PC section. i did Auto configure. it worked. Thank you.